# Is this linear dependent? Because I cannot solve this linear system of equations..

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, vectors

> Are the vectors $v_{1},v_{2},v_{3}$ linear independant?
>
> $$v_{1}=\begin{pmatrix}  &1& \\   &1&\\   &1& 
> \end{pmatrix},v_{2}=\begin{pmatrix}  &1& \\   &0&\\   &0& 
> \end{pmatrix},v_{3}= \begin{pmatrix}  &0& \\   &1&\\   &1& 
> \end{pmatrix}$$

So I wrote this:

$$a\begin{pmatrix}
 &1& \\ 
 &1&\\ 
 &1& 
\end{pmatrix}+b\begin{pmatrix}
 &1& \\ 
 &0&\\ 
 &0& 
\end{pmatrix}+c
\begin{pmatrix}
 &0& \\ 
 &1&\\ 
 &1& 
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
 &0& \\ 
 &0&\\ 
 &0& 
\end{pmatrix}$$

From this we get these linear systems:

$$I: a+b=0$$

$$II: a+c=0$$

$$III: a+c=0$$

But I cannot solve it because II and III is same so actually we only have $2$ systems with $3$ unknowns I don't know what to do...? >.<

Comment: Hint: $v_1=v_2+v_3$.

Comment: $II=III$ means that the system has infinite solutions and so the vectors are dependant.

Comment: @dxiv Oh you are right! So that would mean that none of the variables $a,b,c$ can equal $0$, we have $a=b=c=1$ so it is really linear dependent. (?)

Comment: @cnmesr $a v_1 - a v_2 - a v_3 = 0$ for $\forall a$.

Answer (score 1):

you can write $$b=-a$$ and $$c=-a$$ and your vectors are dependant